# Docker Container: how can the CPU usage percentage be above the total cores amount?

Tags: docker, containers, cpu, cpu-usage, resource-management

Here are the CPU usages of my containers. These values come from a historical collection of `docker stats` output. The VM I'm using has **8 cores** and 32GB of ram.

[container's CPU usage chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFrUX.png)

As seen here https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2134#issuecomment-558056213 As far as I understand, when I have 8 cores, the capacity I can see should be at most 800%, but when I read the green and blue usage, they peak at 750% and 100% at the same time. I would expect their total to be at most 800%. The total amount is 850%.

**How is this possible? How can it exceed 800%?**

I couldn't find an answer about this problem. I am asking for your help.